# How to write the best way to change the image source using conditions Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sub.html:

```
<div>

<img src ="worlds/application/images/aa.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="worlds/application/images/bb.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="worlds/application/images/cc.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="worlds/application/images/dd.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="worlds/application/images/ee.png" class="path"/>

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#main').load( "../sub.html",function(data){
                    var imgSrc = $('.path');
                    var img1 = imgSrc[0].src.split('application')[0]+"css/images/aa.png";
                    var img2 = imgSrc[1].src.split('application')[0]+"css/images/bb.png";
                    var img3 = imgSrc[2].src.split('application')[0]+"css/images/cc.png";
                    var img4 = imgSrc[3].src.split('application')[0]+"css/images/dd.png";
                    var img5 = imgSrc[4].src.split('application')[0]+"css/images/ee.png";
                if(imgSrc[0].src.indexOf('aa')>-1){
                    imgSrc[0].attr('src',img1);
                }
                });
```

Is there any best way to change the path of all the images. What I have tired is I am splitting the path till application node, because I need to append my new url at the application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way of doing what you have done. In this code,  you can have whatever number of images you want, all you need is to have them with `path` as css class.

```
$('#main').load( "../sub.html",function(data){
  var newPath = 'http://localhost:8080/Content/css/images/';
  $.each($('.path'), function(index){
  var originalSource = $(this).attr('src');

  // Replacing the source
  var newSource = newPath + originalSource.substr(originalSource.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  // Setting the new value of src
  $(this).attr('src', newSource);
});
});
```

You can check a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7zs7N/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank u very much it works like a charm, I need a help: My complete URL will be like this : http://localhost:8080/abc/def/ghi/jkl/Content/css/images/aa.png... What ever the code you have given is working fine, but path is giving error, I need to remove ghi and jkl from the path, then it will works for me how to remove that from url

Comment: I updated my answer to fit the requeriment in your comment. However, I recommend you use relative URL instead of absolute URL, it makes your files more portable.

Comment: Thank you very much brother.... have used window.location.href instead of taking http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

Try Like

```
$(".class > img").each(function() {
   var src = $(this).attr('src');           
   $(this).attr('src', 'newsrc');           
});
```

Comment: use with id rather then class (id of div that contains all the imgtags). i.e. $("#ID > img").each(function() {});